# Storing RDF to Triple Store as input: Conversion from CSV to RDF

Tags: python, csv, sparql, rdf, jena

I am using Triple Store called Apache Jena Fuseki for storing the RDF as input But the thing is that i have data in CSV format. I researched a lot but didn't find direct way to convert CSV to RDF but there is tarql tool which is command line tool that can do the job but the thing is that i need a python script that directly converts my CSV to RDF form.

I have used the tools like openRefine and tarql but i need python script to do this job and i have read somewhere that owlready2 tool also used to convert CSV to RDF but when  i used to visit the official site then i found that they are using OWL file for this work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSVW](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-primer/) - CSV on the Web - is a W3C Recommendation for this. There is a [python implementation](https://pypi.org/project/csvw/).

Or you can run "tarql" from python by forking a subprocess.